# Bash read file line by line and append the value to a specific variable

Tags: bash, shell

I a trying to read a file line by line and add the value of each line after making some changes to a variable.
Currently I am using this-

```
COM="Something i"

while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ];
do
   LINE="Line${line/=/,}End"
   COM="$COM$LINE"
done < Vars

COM="$COM done"

echo "Vars" | piping_into_some_other_application
```

The content of file vars-

```
VAL=something
VAL2=somethingelse
VAL3=some
VAL4=vals
```

I finally expect COM to be-
`Something iLineVAL,somethingEndLineVAL2,somethingelseEndLineVAL3,someEndLineVAL4,valsEnd done`
But I get-
`LineVAL4,valsEnd done`

Comment: Unless the input file is saved in DOS format, you can drop the `|| [ -n "$line" ]`. And I strongly recommend *against* using text files saved in DOS format.

Comment: Because of wrong variablenames!! `$LINE  !=  $Line != $line` !!!

Comment: You could use `COM+=Line${line//=/,}End` without quotes!

Comment: Don't use all-capital names at all; they are reserved.

Comment: @chepner There needs to be a global information campaign to promote the proper naming of variables to overcome the decades long worst-practices currently in place.  I swear, many people seem to think that variable names in shell scripts *must* be in all caps.  It is exasperating!

Answer (score 2):

With Your solution `$LINE` and `$COM` gets overwritten with every iteration instead of appending.

You can do this with `gawk` if that is available too look this:

```
awk '{gsub("=",",") ; V = V "Line" $1 "End" } END { print "Something i" V "done"}' INPUTFILE | some_other_application
```

(And You can do it with `sed`, `perl` etc.)

With `bash` it can be done like

```
COM=""
while IFS= read -r line ; do
    COM="${COM}Line${line/=/,}end"
done < INPUTFILE
echo "Something i${COM} done" | some_other_program
```

Comment: Does not work. The first solution Only does for 1 line.
And the second one does not work. Also Perhaps you wanted to say `{COM}` instead of `{COM}`
Also can you tell what `{T}` is for

Comment: @Weirdo914 there were some typos in the bash solution, that got corrected. Please share how the ``awk`` solution does not work?